# Tesseract in Unstructured not recognizing Greek characters in mixed-language PDF

Tags: python, pdf, nlp, tesseract, unstructured-data

I am working with PDFs that contain tables with a mix of Greek characters and English letters (e.g., chemical formulas like α-pinene). I am using Tesseract OCR to extract the text, but it seems to only recognize the English letters, even though I have installed all the necessary language packages from tesseract-lang.

When I inspect the tables using table.metadata.text_as_html, the Greek letters are either missing or replaced with English ones. I suspect there might be a syntax error in my code. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
elements = partition_pdf(filename, languages=["eng", "ell"], strategy="auto", infer_table_structure=True, url=None, model_name = "yolox")
```

Partition_pdf is a function from the unstructured.io library. I have tried passing different language parameters to the languages argument, but the issue persists. Can anyone help me identify what I might be doing wrong or suggest a way to correctly extract both Greek and English characters from the PDF?

Comment: I don't know the library you use, but Tesseract normally accepts multi-language specifications still as one string with language codes joined by "+". So you may have to specificy `languages="eng+ell"`. But as I said: may be different with that package. If you would use PyMuPDF (has integrated Tesseract API), that's the way it works there.

Comment: In this case the language parameter must be a list of language codes as strings.

Comment: Have you tried tesseract standalone or OCRmyPDF package (which uses Tesseract) in CLI mode? Just to confirm that the problem is outside Tesseract ...

Comment: Could you share a example pdf or picture snippet, who shows the problem?